# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I can't locate my "coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow"
This code used to work earlier but I don't know what's the problem.
It is impossible to click on the right arrow button.
Here is my code :

```
from random import randint
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import instapy
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

class InstagramBot:
def __init__(self,username,password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

def login(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
    time.sleep(randint(2, 6))
    email = bot.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
    password = bot.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password + Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(randint(5,6))
    bot.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/div/div/div/button").click()
def searchHashtag(self,hashtag):
    bot = self.bot

    bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag)

def likePhotos(self,amount):

    bot = self.bot

    bot.find_element_by_class_name('v1Nh3').click()

    i = 1

    while i <= amount:
        try:
            time.sleep(randint(2, 6))
            bot.find_elements_by_class_name("_8-yf5").click()
            time.sleep(randint(2, 6))

            i += 1
        except:

            bot.find_element_by_class_name('coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow').click()
            continue
```

I hope you can find the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.